# How to set up dynamic style property to an object property

Tags: javascript, css

Is there anyway I can set up a style property dynamically to an objects property? I tried the code below and got an error.

```
var page = {showElement:'none'};

var markup='<div id="button"> </div><style>#button{display:'+page.showElement+';}</style>';

var mainDiv = document.getElementById('mainDiv');
    mainDiv.innerHTML = markup;
```

Comment: Using JavaScript it's `ElementAnyWayYouWantToGetIt.style.display = `

Answer (score 1):

You already have an ID for your div element, why not use it to change the display property?

```
document.getElementById('button').style.diplay = 'none';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('button').style.diplay = page.showElement;
```

So you dont really need to use:

```
mainDiv.innerHTML
```

Comment: That works, just wanted to see if there was any way you can set style properties dynamically.